# Does simply passing huge amount of props uses any resources?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if simply passing a huge amount of props uses any resources if none of them are actually used.
For example

```
<MyComponent data={data_10kRecord}/>
```

**VS**

```
<MyComponent data={data_SingleRecord}/>
```

MyComponent will use only one of the records and it will use it like this:

```
data[id]
```

**So does the first component use more resources than the second component?**

Answer (score 0):

Well actually the props system in react is actually just a syntactic sugar that is parsed by babel (or other `jsx` parser) For an html element that has a normal object named props. So when you pass the 10k records it will create the props object that holds all the records. So far I think the best practice is to pass only the required record instead of creating a a huge props object that will take a place in the memory.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) and how the bigger your object is the more memory it'll take.